# Hide current time and progress bar on audio element

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to remove the current time and  on a html player. (http://prntscr.com/dvi5a4) I've tried most of the solutions but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Provide proper explaination with some code example.

Comment: <audio controls src="song.mp3" id="stream" autoplay="true" style=" width:500px;">Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>

Answer (score 3):

by using following css, you can hide progress bar only

```
audio::-webkit-media-controls-timeline,
video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {
    display: none;
}
```

and by following css, you can hide duration

```
audio::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display,
audio::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own audio player with js:

```
var sound = document.createElement("audio");
function soundstart()
{
    if (sound != null && sound.canPlayType && sound.canPlayType("audio/mpeg"))
    {
        sound.src = "music/song.mp3";
    }
}
function soundplay()
{
    sound.play();
}
function soundpause()
{
    sound.pause();
}
function soundvolume(volume) // 0.00 to 1
{
    sound.volume = volume;
}
```

soundstart() prepare the audio.

soundplay() play the audio.

soundpause() pause the audio

soundvolume() set volume between 0 and 1

You can create buttons to manage. Don't forget to run soundstart() before play.

Comment: addition window.onload=soundstart; soundstart must contain document.body.appendChild(sound)

Comment: Can I not remove it on the default html player?